# Help with query that changes values right in the db

Tags: mysql, database

I recently migrated domains and in my database, I had stored full paths containing the old domain, which now broke :)

What I need to do is change values in the database table from

http://www.olddomain.com/img/some/path

to

http://www.newdomain/same/dir/structure/as/old/domain

The only caveat is that the photo names at the end of the url must be preserved.  So essentially, I have to just change the host name.

Is that possible to do?  If so, how? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE(column,"www.olddomain.com","www.newdomain.com");`

ALWAYS make sure you do a backup of your database before running a query that updates many records (as this will).

Comment: @AJ is there a way to do this to replace the old domain nothing?  I would also try to see what happens if I end up with paths just like this: /some/path

Comment: This will not work if @Genadinik has composite domain paths, e.g. http://www.olddomain.com/img/some/path, and domain references in text columns, such as in a CMS.

Comment: @Genadinik: You could do `REPLACE(column, 'http://www.olddomain.com', '')` to strip off the old domains completely. I think `REPLACE(column, 'http://www.olddomain.com/img/', '/img/')` might be safer though. And, of course, experiment on a **copy** of your production data.

Answer (score 1):

With a MySQL database, do this on the command line:

1 - Put full DB in a file:

```
mysqldump -uYOURUSERNAME -pYOURPASSWORD YOURDBNAME > YOURDBNAME.sql
```

2 - Replace olddomain.com with newdomain.com in the previous DB file:

```
sed -i 's/olddomain.com/newdomain.com/g' YOURDBNAME.sql
```

3 - Delete all tables in original database (make sure you have a backup), and update database with replaced domain in all rows of all tables, where applicable:

```
mysql -uYOURUSERNAME -pYOURPASSWORD YOURDBNAME < YOURDBNAME.sql
```

This is guaranteed to work. I've used this to update domains on Magento databases (300+ tables) several times.

FYI, **sed** is a linux/unix command line tool for "filtering and transforming text", I don't know if there is a windows version.

PS - If you really need to put slashes (/) in the domain (like if you're replacing www.example.com/sitedir with www.example.com), you should escape the slashes inside the sed string, i.e. instead of using /, use \/. For this example you would do:

```
sed -i 's/www.example.com\/sitedir/www.example.com/g' YOURDBNAME.sql
```